# Natural placement of "however"?

Tags: sentence-construction

Is "however" placed naturally here?

I don't see any of that. The only thing I do see however is a bag that looks suspiciously identical to the one I gave you for your birthday last year.

Comment: What do you think? Are you happy with the construction, apart from missing commas?

Comment: It's my best guess. Is it an obvious place to put it?

Comment: The only thing I do see, however, is a bag that etc.

Answer (score 1):

As a matter of style and taste, "only" and "however" seem to clash somehow. I wonder if either of the following would flow better:

"However, what I do see is ..."

"The only thing I see is ..."

Say all options out loud and see what sounds best to you.

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence with commas before and after **however** is fine.

Most people might say **...looks suspiciously like the one....** rather than **identical to** but that's a matter of style and preference, not grammar. And the **do** is optional, depending on what emphasis you give the sentence.

**The only thing I (do) see, however, is a bag that looks suspiciously (identical to) like the one I gave you for your birthday last year.**